# Is there a way to improve some almost repeated SQL subqueries?

Tags: mysql, subquery, pivot-table, aliases

I'm not pretty good in SQL but there is something that I suspect can be improved in the following query and I can't find a proper way to do it. The main problem is that the full query (I'm showing just a part of the query) is a bit slow and probably this is a point to improve the performance. So I have this simplified query:

```sql
SELECT
tableAa.name as Aa_Name,
tableAu.name as Au_Name,
tableA.code as A_Code,

(select qla.value 
from tableQ as q
left join tableQL as ql on ql.q_id = q.id
left join tableQLA as qla on qla.ql_id = ql.id
left join tableQa as qa on qla.qa_id = qa.id
where ql.enabled is TRUE and ql.archived is FALSE and q.name = 'Some name for tableS'
and qa.id = tableS.qa_id
) as "Some alias for tableS",

(select qla.value 
from tableQ as q
left join tableQL as ql on ql.q_id = q.id
left join tableQLA as qla on qla.ql_id = ql.id
left join tableQa as qa on qla.qa_id = qa.id
where ql.enabled is TRUE and ql.archived is FALSE and q.name = 'Other name for tableS'
and qa.id = tableS.qa_id
) as "Other alias for tableS",
-- more subqueries with exactly the same conditions, except the q.name and alias

(select qla.value 
from tableQ as q
left join tableQL as ql on ql.q_id = q.id
left join tableQLA as qla on qla.ql_id = ql.id
left join tableQa as qa on qla.qa_id = qa.id
where ql.enabled is TRUE and ql.archived is FALSE and q.name = 'Some name for tableA'
and qa.id = tableA.qa_id
) as "Some alias for tableA",

(select qla.value 
from tableQ as q
left join tableQL as ql on ql.q_id = q.id
left join tableQLA as qla on qla.ql_id = ql.id
left join tableQa as qa on qla.qa_id = qa.id
where ql.enabled is TRUE and ql.archived is FALSE and q.name = 'Other Value for tableA'
and qa.id = tableA.qa_id
) as "Other alias for tableA",
-- more subqueries with exactly the same conditions, except the q.name and alias

FROM tableS
LEFT JOIN tableA on tableS.a_id = tableA.id
LEFT JOIN tableAa on tableA.aa_id = tableAa.id
LEFT JOIN tableAu on tableA.au_id = tableAu.id
LEFT JOIN tableQa on tableA.qa_id = tableQa.id
WHERE
--Conditions
ORDER BY --Conditions
```

As you can notice, basically all subqueries are the same except for the where condition (`q.name` and `tableS` vs `tableA`) and for the alias (`as 'Different values for each subquery'`)

Since I see a pattern here, I'm suspecting that it can be improved 'easily', but every single try just ended up in a not good result (surely due to my lack of knowledge). Can anyone help, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some suggestions, it is better using `joins` rather than `subqueries`, anyway without the data and expected results , it is hard to tell. I think you can use `case` rather than making  subqueries

Comment: There are lots of examples of this.  They `JOIN` to tableQ once and use `CASE ..  WHEN` to get the desired `qla.value`.  Follow the tag `[pivot]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RickJames I have would like to find something that could help me with that, but I was not able to. Would you, please, help me with a more concrete example?